# Python and XML parsing non-parent/child data as a group

Tags: python, xml

My goal is to parse an XML file using python ultimately reformatting certain data and writing it to a text file. The issue I am having is that the specific data I want to obtain does not have a parent/child relationship. The data is essentially bracketed by a start element and an end element. My ideas so far:

1. Make a list of the start and end elements IDs or location
2. Iterate through the elements and compare each element ID or location to see if it falls within the bracketed sets from 1

My question, is this even the right place to start? Below is a piece of the XML and I am trying to get all the data that falls between the `<StartRoundsRecord ID="0000006f" TimeStamp="2022-11-29T09:00:10"/>` and the
`<EndRoundsRecord ID="0000007c" TimeStamp="2022-11-29T09:00:47"/>`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<JOBFile jobName="185968_22_333_1" version="5.72" product="Trimble Access" productVersion="22.00" productDBVersion="2200-16" controllerSerialNumber="DAD181502429" TimeStamp="2022-11-29T08:57:38"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.trimble.com/schema/JobXML/5_7 http://www.trimble.com/schema/JobXML/5_7/JobXMLSchema-5.72.xsd">
    <FieldBook>

        <EllipsoidRecord ID="00000003" TimeStamp="2022-11-29T08:57:38">
            <EarthRadius/>
            <Flattening/>
        </EllipsoidRecord>

        <ProjectionRecord ID="00000004" TimeStamp="2022-11-29T08:57:38">
            <Projection>
                <Type>ScaleOnly</Type>
                <Scale>1</Scale>
            </Projection>
            <LocalSite>
                <Type>Grid</Type>
                <ProjectLocationLatitude/>
                <ProjectLocationLongitude/>
                <ProjectLocationHeight/>
            </LocalSite>
        </ProjectionRecord>

        <StartRoundsRecord ID="0000006f" TimeStamp="2022-11-29T09:00:10"/>

        <StartRoundRecord ID="00000070" TimeStamp="2022-11-29T09:00:10">
            <Round>1</Round>
        </StartRoundRecord>

        <TargetRecord ID="00000066" TimeStamp="2022-11-29T09:00:26">
            <PrismType>CustomPrism</PrismType>
            <PrismConstant>-0.03</PrismConstant>
            <TargetHeight>1.7038354076708</TargetHeight>
            <RawTargetHeight>
                <MeasurementMethod>TrueHeight</MeasurementMethod>
                <MeasuredHeight>1.7038354076708</MeasuredHeight>
                <HorizontalOffset>0</HorizontalOffset>
                <VerticalOffset>0</VerticalOffset>
            </RawTargetHeight>
        </TargetRecord>

        <PointRecord ID="00000067" TimeStamp="2022-11-29T09:00:10">
            <Name>16</Name>
            <Code>1INIPW/PP</Code>
            <Method>DirectReading</Method>
            <SurveyMethod>Fix</SurveyMethod>
            <Classification>Normal</Classification>
            <Deleted>false</Deleted>

            <Circle>
                <HorizontalCircle>37.6303464</HorizontalCircle>
                <VerticalCircle>90.2625264</VerticalCircle>
                <EDMDistance>117.4012</EDMDistance>
                <Face>Face1</Face>
                <HorizontalCircleStandardError>0.00027777777778</HorizontalCircleStandardError>
                <VerticalCircleStandardError>0.00027777777778</VerticalCircleStandardError>
                <EDMDistanceStandardError>0.0022348024</EDMDistanceStandardError>
                <EDMMeasurementMode>Fine</EDMMeasurementMode>
            </Circle>
            <StationID>00000053</StationID>
            <BackBearingID>00000054</BackBearingID>
            <TargetID>00000066</TargetID>
            <Pressure>1013.5459756583</Pressure>
            <Temperature>12.777777777778</Temperature>

            <ComputedGrid>
                <North>197106.38447583</North>
                <East>487316.07639709</East>
                <Elevation>192.63673294119</Elevation>
            </ComputedGrid>
            <Notes>
                <Note>Modified 10:36:44 AM 11/29/2022</Note>
                <Note>Old point name 16C</Note>
            </Notes>
        </PointRecord>

        <PointRecord ID="0000006b" TimeStamp="2022-11-29T09:00:19">
            <Name>16</Name>
            <Code>1INIPW/PP</Code>
            <Method>DirectReading</Method>
            <SurveyMethod>Fix</SurveyMethod>
            <Classification>Normal</Classification>
            <Deleted>false</Deleted>

            <Circle>
                <HorizontalCircle>217.6297299</HorizontalCircle>
                <VerticalCircle>269.7371991</VerticalCircle>
                <EDMDistance>117.40189</EDMDistance>
                <Face>Face2</Face>
                <HorizontalCircleStandardError>0.00027777777778</HorizontalCircleStandardError>
                <VerticalCircleStandardError>0.00027777777778</VerticalCircleStandardError>
                <EDMDistanceStandardError>0.00223480378</EDMDistanceStandardError>
                <EDMMeasurementMode>Fine</EDMMeasurementMode>
            </Circle>
            <StationID>00000053</StationID>
            <BackBearingID>00000054</BackBearingID>
            <TargetID>00000066</TargetID>
            <Pressure>1013.5459756583</Pressure>
            <Temperature>12.777777777778</Temperature>

            <ComputedGrid>
                <North>197106.38737123</North>
                <East>487316.0737672</East>
                <Elevation>192.63616748002</Elevation>
            </ComputedGrid>
            <Notes>
                <Note>Modified 10:36:44 AM 11/29/2022</Note>
                <Note>Old point name 16C</Note>
            </Notes>
        </PointRecord>

        <EndRoundRecord ID="00000071" TimeStamp="2022-11-29T09:00:26"/>

        <StartRoundRecord ID="0000007a" TimeStamp="2022-11-29T09:00:34">
            <Round>2</Round>
        </StartRoundRecord>

        <PointRecord ID="00000072" TimeStamp="2022-11-29T09:00:34">
            <Name>16</Name>
            <Code>1INIPW/PP</Code>
            <Method>DirectReading</Method>
            <SurveyMethod>Fix</SurveyMethod>
            <Classification>Normal</Classification>
            <Deleted>false</Deleted>

            <Circle>
                <HorizontalCircle>37.630215</HorizontalCircle>
                <VerticalCircle>90.2616921</VerticalCircle>
                <EDMDistance>117.39994</EDMDistance>
                <Face>Face1</Face>
                <HorizontalCircleStandardError>0.00027777777778</HorizontalCircleStandardError>
                <VerticalCircleStandardError>0.00027777777778</VerticalCircleStandardError>
                <EDMDistanceStandardError>0.00223479988</EDMDistanceStandardError>
                <EDMMeasurementMode>Fine</EDMMeasurementMode>
            </Circle>
            <StationID>00000053</StationID>
            <BackBearingID>00000054</BackBearingID>
            <TargetID>00000066</TargetID>
            <Pressure>1013.5459756583</Pressure>
            <Temperature>12.777777777778</Temperature>

            <ComputedGrid>
                <North>197106.38364849</North>
                <East>487316.07541938</East>
                <Elevation>192.6384477215</Elevation>
            </ComputedGrid>
            <Notes>
                <Note>Modified 10:36:44 AM 11/29/2022</Note>
                <Note>Old point name 16C</Note>
            </Notes>
        </PointRecord>

        <PointRecord ID="00000076" TimeStamp="2022-11-29T09:00:43">
            <Name>16</Name>
            <Code>1INIPW/PP</Code>
            <Method>DirectReading</Method>
            <SurveyMethod>Fix</SurveyMethod>
            <Classification>Normal</Classification>
            <Deleted>false</Deleted>

            <Circle>
                <HorizontalCircle>217.6297407</HorizontalCircle>
                <VerticalCircle>269.7377067</VerticalCircle>
                <EDMDistance>117.40069</EDMDistance>
                <Face>Face2</Face>
                <HorizontalCircleStandardError>0.00027777777778</HorizontalCircleStandardError>
                <VerticalCircleStandardError>0.00027777777778</VerticalCircleStandardError>
                <EDMDistanceStandardError>0.00223480138</EDMDistanceStandardError>
                <EDMMeasurementMode>Fine</EDMMeasurementMode>
            </Circle>
            <StationID>00000053</StationID>
            <BackBearingID>00000054</BackBearingID>
            <TargetID>00000066</TargetID>
            <Pressure>1013.5459756583</Pressure>
            <Temperature>12.777777777778</Temperature>

            <ComputedGrid>
                <North>197106.38641113</North>
                <East>487316.07305499</East>
                <Elevation>192.63721276808</Elevation>
            </ComputedGrid>
            <Notes>
                <Note>Modified 10:36:44 AM 11/29/2022</Note>
                <Note>Old point name 16C</Note>
            </Notes>
        </PointRecord>

        <EndRoundRecord ID="0000007b" TimeStamp="2022-11-29T09:00:47"/>

        <EndRoundsRecord ID="0000007c" TimeStamp="2022-11-29T09:00:47"/>
```

I was able to create an array of the start and end IDs but do not know if comparing ids to my array will even work:

```py
for item in root.findall('./FieldBook'):

    #iterate child elements of item
    for child in item:
        if child.tag == 'StartRoundsRecord':
            startrounds.append(child.attrib['ID'])
        if child.tag == 'EndRoundsRecord':
            endrounds.append(child.attrib['ID'])

rounds = list(zip(startrounds, endrounds))
print(rounds)
```

Also, by printing the element record I can get the location within the file:

```py
for x in root.iter('StartRoundsRecord'):
    print(x)
```

Would this be a better way to group the elements?

Comment: You may like to know that there's a vast literature on so-called "overlap markup". You may also like to know that it's not going to help you very much; it's still a tough problem.

Comment: There is no data between `StartRoundsRecord ` and `EndRoundsRecord `, this two are empty tags you can see that on `/>`. Could you please detail, what you are search for and post a valid XML example, please.